# the program shows unicode error

Tags: python

the below program shows unicode error

```
import urllib2
import csv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'http://www.icc-cricket.com/associate-affiliate-rankings'
response = requests.get(url)
html = response.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
table= soup.find('div', attrs={'class': 'associateRankings'})
list_of_rows = []
for row in table.findAll('tr'):
    list_of_cells = []
    for cell in row.findAll('td'):
        text = cell.text.replace('&nbsp;', '')
        list_of_cells.append(text)
    list_of_rows.append(list_of_cells)

outfile = open("./i.csv", "wb")
writer = csv.writer(outfile)
writer.writerows(list_of_rows)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\web\hi.py", line 20, in <module>
    writer.writerows(list_of_rows)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa0' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

How to fix this error?

Comment: try Replacing `list_of_cells.append(text)` with `list_of_cells.append(text.encode("utf-8"))`

Comment: Always tell if your using python 2 or 3. Especially with codec errors.

Answer (score 0):

## Use this in a loop for all files (eg. happy1.docx) and in  place of abc.txt it will be happy1.txt

################################################################33333

path= 'C:\Users\ANIRBAN ROY\Desktop\sentiment2020\negetive'

files=[]
for r,d,f in os.walk(path):
    for file in f:
        if'.txt' in  file:
            files.append(os.path.join(r,file))

for f in files:
    print(f)

```
file=codecs.open(f,"r","Utf-8")




words=file.split()





    # break the string into list of words  
str = words        
str2 = [] 

    # loop till string values present in list str 
for i in str:              

    # checking for the duplicacy 
        if i not in str2: 

        # insert value in str2 
            str2.append(i)  

for i in range(0, len(str2)): 

    # count the frequency of each word(present  
    # in str2) in str and print 
   print('Frequency of', str2[i], 'is :', str.count(str2[i])) 
file2= codecs.open('abc.txt','w','utf8')
for line in words:
  file2.write(line)
  file2.write("\n")

file.close()
```